# Adding a new value to an existing ENUM Type In prisma

Tags: postgresql, prisma, prisma-graphql, typegraphql

```
    Database error: Error querying the database: db error: ERROR: ALTER TYPE ... ADD cannot be executed from a function or multi-command string
```

I am using prisma as an orm and I have a table column that uses an enum type. I wish to update that enum type to have an additional possible value. I do not want to delete any existing values, just add the new value. when i am adding a new value and  migrate prisma its shows an error like this

What am i doing wrong or is there any better way to add a new value to an existing ENUM type

Comment: Please post was your complete statement, not just the error message.  In Postgres it is a relative simple [ALTER TYPE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertype.html) add value vvvv; The most difficult may be deciding the sort order you want. Not sure how this translates to your obscurification manager (prisma).

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug with older PostgreSQL versions and Prisma.

https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/7251

Upgrading to PostgreSQL version 12 or higher should resolve this error. Alternatively, you can create single migration files whose only purpose is to update the enum.